# How can I start JavaScript with a button click (on WordPress)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I want to insert a button in a page WordPress that open this a JavaScript when a click happened.

The HTML script is this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <script type="text/javascript"> 
     test=()=>{
    var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.src = 'https://www.jdoodle.com/assets/jdoodle-pym.min.js';
   var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
   head.appendChild(script);
   }
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="test()" value="test">
 <div height="200px" width="300px" data-pym- src="https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/x6e?rw=1"></div>


  </body>
</html>
```

I've tried to insert a jquery version like this.
On wordpress page

```
<button onclick="F()">Click me</button>
```

and in functions.php

```
function javascript_footer() {
    ?>
        <script>
          // your javscript code goes

        function F(){
          alert("test");
         $.getScript("https://www.jdoodle.com/assets/jdoodle-pym.min.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
        });
          alert("stop");
        }
        </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'wpb_hook_javascript_footer');
```

What's is wrong? it seems that it doesn't load property the script.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### Enqueue your script.

See [wp_enqueue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) for more details.

```
/**
 * Enqueue a script with jQuery as a dependency.
 */
function wpdocs_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_scripts_method' );
```

#### Your problems though

Is that you're currently not declaring your anonymous function `test()`

Try:

```
const test = () => {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'https://www.jdoodle.com/assets/jdoodle-pym.min.js';
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
  head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jonathan
The script that declaring my anonymous function test() goes into functions.php or elsewhere?

Comment: Inside PHP you can either echo out a script tag, or if it's a template file you can just add the script tag.   In your example, you had `test = () => {}` which will throw an error on `test()`.    You need to make the function a `const` (or other variable, try not to use var btw)